# Deleting row from dynamically populated list

Tags: php, html, opencart

Working in OpenCart MVC and things are clearer.THis code is revised since the delete function technically works now, butdeleting from the list of multiple records it always deletes the last one is my code. It doesn't matter which one you choose the var _dump always shows the id from the last record.

Model:

```
public function deleteCampaign($campaign_id) {


    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "campaigns` WHERE campaign_id = '" . (int)$campaign_id . "'");

    var_dump("DELETE FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "campaigns` WHERE campaign_id = '" . (int)$campaign_id . "'");
    exit;
    return $campaign_id;
}
```

Controller:

```
   public function delete() {
        $this->load->language('campaigns/campaign');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $this->load->model('campaigns/campaign');



        if (isset($this->request->post['campaign_id'])) {
    $campaign_id = $this->request->post['campaign_id'];
    $this->model_campaigns_campaign->deleteCampaign($campaign_id);

            $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('campaigns/campaign', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, true));
        }
        $this->getList();
    }
```

View:

```
 <div class="panel-body" id="campaign-body">
    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-order">

      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table" id="campaign-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $column_campaign_id; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $column_campaign; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $column_giving_goal; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $column_giving_count_goal; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $column_owner; ?></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php if ($orders) { ?>
            <?php foreach ($orders as $order) { ?>
            <tr class="campaign-list">

              <td><?php echo $order['campaign_id']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $order['campaign_name']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $order['campaign_giving_goal']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $order['campaign_giving_count_goal']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $order['campaign_owner']; ?></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="campaign_id" value="<?php echo $order['campaign_id']; ?>" />
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="campaign-dropdown-btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><?php echo $text_campaign_dropdown;?><span class="caret"></span></button>
                  <ul class="campaign-list-more dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="campaign-dropdown-list">Edit</li>
                    <li class="campaign-dropdown-list">Archive</li>
                    <li class="campaign-dropdown-list">
                        <button type="submit" id="campaign-del" name="deleteButton" onclick="javascript:changeFormAction('<?php echo $delete; ?>');">
                            <?php echo $button_delete; ?>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </td>

            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <tr>
              <td class="text-center" colspan="8"><?php echo $text_no_results; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 text-left"><?php echo $pagination; ?></div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 text-right"><?php echo $results; ?></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[The results of changing hidden to text in the input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5rj7.png)

Comment: Could you please show us the form, with one record in it?

Comment: I added code from 2 template files. The first I added is fro the form that the info is entered on. the second bit of code if from the form that lists the data. I hope this is what you are asking for

Comment: For sure is what I asked for. And more... Do you need some infos from us regarding the first form too?

Comment: well yes, Im trying to get the delete option to work but there is also a edit option which when clicked will launch the first form code I sent. This time though the inputs should be filled with whatever was entered into that record. This is the next problem Im going to solve.

Comment: Well, first things first.

Comment: yeah, the first thing is most important, Ill worry about the other problem next

Comment: I'm done. I'm not sure why are you using `$_REQUEST` in model. The reading of the HTTP request values (from the GET, POST, etc request methods) should be the controller's responsibility. The controller passes these values then to the model as method arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step: delete record.

### The working principle:

When you are clicking on a delete button, a javascript function is called (changeFormAction). The function changes the form's action to the given action name ("delete") before the form is submitted. The given action name corresponds to the controller action.

For each campaign record, the campaign id is saved as the value of the delete button's `value` attribute. Upon submitting the form, its value will be read in the controller action `delete()` and the model method `deleteCampaign()` will be called, receiving it as argument.

### In HTML:

Put this script in the `<head>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /**
     * Change form action dependent of the clicked form button.
     * 
     * @param action string Form action.
     * @return bool
     */
    function changeFormAction(action) {
        var form = document.getElementById('form-order');
        form.action = action;
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

After that replace the last `<li>` tag in dropddown with with:

```
<li class="campaign-dropdown-list">
    <button type="submit" name="deleteButton" value="<?php echo $order['campaign_id']; ?>" onclick="javascript:changeFormAction('<?php echo $delete; ?>');">
        <?php echo $button_delete; ?>
    </button>
</li>
```

### In Controller:

```
if (isset($this->request->post['deleteButton']) && $this->validateDelete()) {
    $campaign_id = $this->request->post['deleteButton'];
    $this->model_campaigns_campaign->deleteCampaign($campaign_id);

    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I appreciate the explanation. I have not gotten it to work yet, but I will keep working with it to see if I can figure out the issue. error Log says that in  the last line of the controller function ($this) is unexpected. The request in the model was just some trial and error leftover I was doing.

Comment: So close! I got it working, but now when the list has several records on it and I try to delete one it always removes the last record. on a var_dump it shows that its always selecting the last records id.

Comment: added an image to show new results.input shows corresponding id

Comment: the problem is still there, looking at the image if I select the first record(id=22) for deletion it still deletes the last record(id-26) No matter how many records it always deletes the bottom row

Comment: @Anon_guy I reedited the answer. The problem was, that for one form I put more hidden inputs with the same name! My bad, sorry. So, now each delete button has the value. Just revise the codes (HTML `li` and controller) in my answer and delete the hidden input completely. Please note that you should NOT display any db ID's. If you have to use the id's in any form (not `form` tag) in HTML, then find a way to present an encoded version of them. And, when you post them, decode them in php (in controller, or model, etc) and work with them as normal afterwards.

Comment: Ohh man, thanks for this. Im really trying to understand what this entails, so setting the value of the delete button to the campaign id gives each record a delete option unique to that record?

Comment: @Anon_guy With pleasure. Exactly. Each submit button is unique by definition, because only the clicked one will be recognized as posted element by the PHP. And as a result, only the value of the clicked button will be sent. E.g. only the corresponding id.

Comment: @Anon_guy There are other methods too: 1) to use an anchor (like in your original code) instead of a button, and to just hang the id as a query string parameter. But this would have been a good idea only with a strong encoding of the id. The button method at least hides the id implementation under the browser hood. Still: encode the value. 2) Define only one hidden input per form and set its value on button click with the corresponding id from the button's value attribute, with js, before submitting. That way you could give it the elegant name "campaign_id".

Comment: @Anon_guy A matter of taste if you want to do that. By using my button method you don't need an extra js code line and a hidden input. But that would be absolutely ok way too... Bye.